# Spring Boot IntelliJ Make Project not working for static files

Tags: angularjs, spring, intellij-idea

I have a Spring Boot (1.3.5.RELEASE) project in IntelliJ 15.
My web application is AngularJS based. If I edit a html file in the src/resources/static folder and press CTRL+F9 (Make Project) the updates are not synchroizied to the target folder of the project. Why is intellJ deleting the files during "make project"?

What is an easy way to sync the src/static folder with the target dir?